# Drupal Multisite RedirectMatch on main site only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal

I am running a Drupal multi site and on the main site i need to redirect around 600 pages. I am using:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tags/manchester_conference$ http://mainsite.com/tags/health-and-safety-events/manchester_conference
```

These are effecting the multisite too if they also have a page called /tags/manchester_conference

How can i get this to only work on the main site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the solution is to make sure the rule is applied only for main site using mod_rewrite in one .htaccess file at root directory.

Something like this should work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?mainsite\.com    [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/health-and-safety-events/manchester_conference  [NC]
RewriteRule ^tags/manchester_conference  /tags/health-and-safety-events/manchester_conference  [R=301,L,NC]
```